# Adjective for having enough and satisfactory food

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, compound-adjectives

I have eaten enough food. The food was delicious and may be I have eaten a lot more than required. I enjoyed it. Now I am very happy about it. How to describe this? Should we say "I have had enough food/ satisfactory meal" or should it be "a decent meal". Somebody suggested me "bellyful" which I don't think is right in this situation because 'bellyful' talks about only quantity. Please suggest right vocabulary.

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin with this question. For this site, all your suggestions would require research (i.e. evidence of what you found in dictionaries or phrasebooks) to show why you they are / aren't appropriate. Even if you'd done that, the variety of possible answers would probably make this "too broad" and "primarily opinion based". I've suggested it may be a better fit on English Language and Learners (ell.stackexchange.com), as I think they'd be more welcoming of open-ended questions.

Comment: Thanks for your ardent reply. I think sharing of personal experiences and usage preferences will help a lot.  I have just joined ell. Let me post the question there also. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a duplicate of a [question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/146675/37759). Cross-posting is normally frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you are looking for may be "sated":
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sate

> Satisfy (a desire or an appetite) to the full.

...you could use "satisfied", but sated is just a bit stronger.

Just to add that the above would describe your state after such a meal e.g. "I was sated after the delicious meal". However, if you are looking to describe the meal, an adjective like "sumptuous" would imply both quantity and quality, while a noun like feast or banquet would augment this.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sumptuous

> Sumptuous: Splendid and expensive-looking.
>   ‘the banquet was a sumptuous, luxurious meal’

So, combining all the above you could say:

> I was fully sated following the sumptuous feast you prepared for me.

Comment: You're very welcome Ramachandra!

Answer (score 2):

You could say that you are [replete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/replete):

> fully or abundantly provided or filled.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/replete) describe it as:

> Very full of or sated by food.

Answer (score 1):

> [satiated](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/satiated) - To satisfy (an appetite, for example) fully. [The Free Dictionary]

I like to employ this after a good meal.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you linked to and quoted a source, to help others who wished to follow up.